# OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad() allways returns the same value

Tags: java

I'm trying to measure CPU load with the following code

```
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

System.out.println(((OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getSystemCpuLoad());
```

But it always prints 0.20614 ± 0.00001. Even after 3 minutes of full CPU load. Which is **looks like average load for the whole uptime**. But there is no uptime in javadoc, there is "recent".

> Returns the "recent cpu usage"

- 2 CPU × 6 cores
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
- CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)